# how to select tags between two tags that has no specific attribute using xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

my xml looks like this:

```
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>

<table>
<!--some tr and td's-->
</table>
<p><sup>a</sup> text</p>
<p><sup>b</sup> text</p>
<p><sup>c</sup> text</p>
<p></p>

<table>
<!--some tr and td's-->
</table>
<p><sup>a</sup> text</p>
<p><sup>b</sup> text</p>

<p>text</p>
```

i need to select p tags which are following-siblings of the first table and preceding-siblings of the empty p.

Comment: not clear about your requirement here. Also you haven't specified what have you tried on your end. And how your desired output looks like!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your XPath interpreter supports XPath 2.0, there is a nice solution using `intersects`:

```
//table/following-sibling::p
    intersect
//p[data()='']/preceding-sibling::p
```

The first line fetches all paragraphs after the table, the third line all before the empty paragraph. The intersection is the desired result.